# 'docker run' with hub images fails. Difference between Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04, and (nearly) every `docker run` command I issue results in some sort of error.

- `docker run -it --rm --name my-apache-app -v "$PWD":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4` results in the error `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /usr/local/bin/httpd-foreground`.
- `docker run --name my-nginx nginx` results in the error `nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied)`
- `docker run --name my-mysql mysql:5.7` results in the error `/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied`

When I run these *exact same commands* on my 18.04 machine I have *no* issues—they all run perfectly fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What are the flags on the files in both cases (on the host and looking from the container)? Is it the same Docker version? Are you in the `docker` group on both machines? What is the id of the container process, as seen from the host?

Comment: Obviously a permission issue. I'm sure different Ubu versions issue different ownership/permissions of various files. Not saying that's the case just a potential explanation. Personally, assuming **"$PWD"** relates to a password, that is where I'd focus my debugging. Don't assume that every command gets executed exactly the same across updates. Breakdown the command, argument by argument. What works, what doesn't? Do similar functions work? When and where does permissions become an issue?

Comment: **"$PWD"** is the local current directory, mapping to `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/` in the container. As for the flags on the other files, I have no idea. The containers don't start, so I can't get into them to find out what the flags on them are from that point of view. The files don't exist on the local machine, which is part of the point of having the container. I am in the docker group on both machines, but I get the same result if I run with `sudo`.